# Evaluation of Sobolev ($L^p$) function actually well defined?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

I will ask a similar question to the one from yesterday. If we have

$$\displaystyle\int_Ef(x,t)|^{\tau_2}_{\tau_1}\,dx$$

where $f$ is a Sobolev function (or maybe even just some $L^p$ function) (not neccessarily continuous) on a space-time cylinder. Is this pointwise evaluation in $\tau_2$ and $\tau_1$ without the extra assumption $f\in C([\tau_1,\tau_2])$ actually well defined/possible? I saw this yesterday and am confused now because Sobolev (and $L^p$) functions are merely defined a.e....or is this alright since we are safe as long we are "under" the integral where it's anyways always just a.e. of matter?

Maybe I am misunderstanding something here. Thanks in advance and br!

Comment: Since $L^p$ functions are actually equivalence classes of functions, point evaluations are not well-defined without context. However, evaluation of a Sobolev function along the boundary of the domain can be defined in a natural way, and the resulting operator is called the [*trace operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the trace. I thought about making sense of the evaluation above as follows: Let's take some function g, defined in $\tau_2$ and $\tau_1$ such that $f=g$ a.e..Then the evaluation should work right?

Comment: If only $L^p$, then I'd say no: Fubini-Tonelli gives that $t\mapsto\int_E f(x,t)\, dx$ is only an $L^p$ function in $t$. On the other hand, for Sobolev functions, you should have that the map above is continuous in $t$ (at least that's my intuition).

Comment: Also, if $f$ is a Sobolev function in time, then the evaluation should make sense as Sobolev functions in 1D (here in time) are continuous anyway I think...

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is best understood if you study the operator $$T : f \mapsto f(\cdot,t)|_{t=\tau_1}^{t=\tau_2}. $$ If you only assume $f\in L^p(E=\Omega\times[\tau_1,\tau_2])$, I don't think $T$ is a continuous operator, preventing us from extending $T|_{C(E)\cap L^p(E)}$ to all of $L^p(E)$. On the other hand, borrowing (or mimicking the proof of) the trace theorem, I believe $T$ is indeed a continuous operator on $W^{1,p}(E)$.

Comment: Hm thanks guys! I am really confused why the authors don't mention anything regarding meaning of this expression (as this is their main result even more so actually)...

Comment: Would it actually change anything if we had $0<\tau_1<\tau_2<T$, so $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ in the interior of some interval $[0,T]$? I am super confused right now with this pointwise evaluation...

Comment: Perhaps it is best to think everything in terms of operators. For example, "evaluating $f$ at $x$" in functional analysis is nothing but considering the evaluation operator $\delta_x:f\mapsto f(x)$. So, the question would be whether $\delta_x$ is a well-defined (and continuous) operator on the function space you are looking at. By the way, I have not enough expertise in this subject to claim anything affirmatively, so I would suggest you to post this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: The question boils down to the question whether the specific Sobolev space is continously embedded into spaces of continuous functions/or has traces on the boundary of domains. Look into the corresponding Sobolev embedding/trace theorems.